# edit text input React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, firebase

Is there any way of inject text of database into the input to be editable? not like placeholder.

Here is a picture as example.

In this case the text is placed as placeholder and obviously can not be editable without erase all.

Here is the code:

```
<div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper}>
            <form className="update-note create-note">
              <input
                className="input-edit-note"
                name="title"
                onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.currentTarget.value)}
                value={title}
                placeholder={props.title}
              />

              <textarea
                name="content"
                onChange={(e) => setContent(e.currentTarget.value)}
                value={content}
                placeholder={props.content}
              />
              <Fab onClick={submitNote}>
                <AddCircleIcon />
              </Fab>
            </form>
          </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you put in `value={...}` will be visible to edit in the textfield.
If it's props that you want to merge with component local data then I'd suggest doing so via useState and useEffect

Either this:

```
const Example = (props) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.title);
  ...
}
```

or like this

```
const Example = (props) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setTitle(props.title);
  }, [props.title]);
  ...
}
```

And then use the value in the input tag

```
<input
  ...
  value={title}
  ...
/>
```

Example component:

```
// When initiating this component, make sure to pass "title" as props
const Example = (props) => {
  // Title is bound to state within this component
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.title);
  
  const _onChangeTitle = e => {
    setTitle(e.target.value);
  }
  
  return (
    <input
      className="input-edit-note"
      name="title"
      onChange={_onChangeTitle}
      value={title}             // title will always be state title
      placeholder={props.title} // props.title will always remain the same
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the prev messege, now I removed the placeholder and what it happens is that the input field is empty

Comment: Alright, no worries. I'll update with a full component as example in a lil bit.

Answer (score 1):

once you get your data from you db save it in your component state as i see you're already doing:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.title);
  ...
}
```

then set theinput's value equal to the title data you recieve from your db.
At the onChange trigger the `setTitle` function that will update your `title` state.

```
<input
  className="YourProfileInput"
  placeholder="Insert Title"
  value={title}
  onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.currentTarget.value)}
/>
```

Comment: Works, but when I try to edit the note for a second time the input field shows empty.

Comment: what do you mean with "for a second time"?